# Correct kernel parameters - Asus GL553VE dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, touchpad, battery, acpi

I am trying to dual boot with Windows 10 on a SSD and Ubuntu 17.10 on a Hard Drive (both UEFI) on a Asus Rog Strix GL553VE.

To be able to boot up on Ubuntu I had to add `acpi=off` as a kernel parameter.

After the clean installation of Ubuntu alongside Windows none of the fn-keys worked, nor did the touchpad or the battery status.

I manage to make the system boot correctly and show the battery only using `acpi_osi=` instead of `acpi=off`. Moreover, if I add `nomodeset` the touchpad works but the fn-keys still do not work (except for the brightness ones).
I am pretty sure that this is not a solution, as sometimes Ubuntu becomes extremely laggy and the fans are really loud.

**Update**:

I solved the `nomodeset` problem by adding `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` in the grub configuration file (*/etc/default/grub*) instead of `nomodeset acpi=off` at the end of the line that starts with **Linux**. This solution seems ok, it's explanation is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110624/what-do-the-kernel-parameters-acpi-osi-linux-and-acpi-backlight-vendor-do).

Now I found out that my keyboard lightning intensity doesn't change using the functional keys and when I close the top it doesn't go to stand-by. I will come back with the solution (if found). Hope this will help someone as I lost more than 3 days breaking and repairing the system.